# Shopping Cart page displays only one item

Tags: java, jsf

I'm developing a Java EE e-commerce application that will sell car parts. I can add items to the shopping cart implemented using CopyOnWriteArrayList. I then use a managed bean (session scoped) to display its contents. 
I then use a  to display the data in ViewCode.xhtml. The probelsm is: It will only show the first item in the arraylist. Please can someone help?
The Managed Bean:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="ViewCartManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ViewCartManagedBean {
    List<Orderitem> cartItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    @EJB
    com.shop.cart.CartFacade cartFacade;

    public ViewCartManagedBean(){}

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        setCartItemsList();
    }
    public List<Orderitem> getCartItemsList() {
        return cartItemsList;
    }

    public void setCartItemsList() {
        cartItemsList = cartFacade.viewItemsIntheCart();
    }

}
```

The cart facade

```
  @Stateless(name="ShoppingCartLocal")
    public class CartFacade {
        @PersistenceContext(unitName ="Shop")
        EntityManager cartEntityManager;
        @EJB
        ShoppingCart cartBean;

        public CartFacade(){}

    public void assignCustomerToCart(CustomerEntity customer){
        cartBean.setCustomer(customer);
    }
    public boolean addItemToCart(ProductEntity product, int quantityPurchased){
        boolean result = false;
        result=cartBean.addCartItem(product, quantityPurchased);
        return result;
    }

    public List<Orderitem> viewItemsIntheCart(){
        return cartBean.getCartItems();
    }


the ShoppingCartBean

@Stateful(name="ShoppingCart")
@StatefulTimeout(value = 200)

public class ShoppingCartBean implements ShoppingCart,ShoppingCartLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName ="Shop", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
     private EntityManager cartEntityManager;

     private CustomerManager customerManagerBean;
     private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> cartItems= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem>();
     private  CustomerEntity customer=null;

     public  CustomerEntity getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public  void setCustomer(CustomerEntity customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        System.out.println("hey Im linked to the cart " + customer.getName());
    }
    private com.shop.entity.Orderitem basketItem=new Orderitem();

    public ShoppingCartBean(){}
    @PostConstruct

    public void initialise(){
        //cartItems = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem>();
    }

    public void removeCartItem(int itemCode){
        System.out.println("hello");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean addCartItem(ProductEntity product, int quantityPurchased){
        double subTotal;
        boolean result=false;
        if (cartItems.size()==0){
            basketItem.setItemcode(product.getItemcode());
            basketItem.setItemdescription(product.getItemdescription());
            basketItem.setUnitprice(product.getUnitprice());
            basketItem.setQuantitypurchased(quantityPurchased);
            subTotal=quantityPurchased*basketItem.getUnitprice();
            basketItem.setSubtotal(subTotal);
            cartItems.add(basketItem);
            result=true;
        }else{
            Iterator<Orderitem> basketIterator = cartItems.iterator();
            while (basketIterator.hasNext()){
                Orderitem cartItem = basketIterator.next();
                System.out.println("cart item item code: " + cartItem.getItemcode());
                System.out.println("product item code: " + product.getItemcode());
                if(cartItems.size()!=0 && !(cartItem.getItemcode().equals((product.getItemcode())))){       
                    basketItem.setItemcode(product.getItemcode());
                    basketItem.setItemdescription(product.getItemdescription());
                    basketItem.setUnitprice(product.getUnitprice());
                    basketItem.setQuantitypurchased(quantityPurchased);
                    subTotal=quantityPurchased*basketItem.getUnitprice();
                    basketItem.setSubtotal(subTotal);
                    cartItems.add(basketItem);
                    result=true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("cart size " + cartItems.size());
        return result;
    }
```

Finally the view (ViewCart.xhtml)

```
<h:form name="ViewCartManagedBean">

<h:dataTable var="cartList" value="#{ViewCartManagedBean.cartItemsList}"
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" >
    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Item Code" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;"/></f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cartList.itemcode}" style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"/>
   </h:column>
```

Comment: Just a quick codereview tip: your sessionbean is returning it's inner list. You might want to consider copying the content and returning a copy of the list (or array) as you don't want anyone to do: getCartItemList().add(someItem) . currently this is possible

Comment: Have you debugged this application and checked in the debugger if cartList is actually filled with more than 1 item?

Comment: Maintaining/managing/manipulating a shopping cart/basket can be done by the application client itself using a user's session (a session scoped JSF/CDI bean itself is quite sufficient). Thus, a stateful session bean in this case, is absolutely superfluous. You are maintaining a costly stateful session bean using a verbose/extended persistence context (`PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`) and making costly calls to the session bean quite unnecessarily. Please reconsider the design itself. Moreover, stateful session beans are not managed beans. You will need to explicitly destroy them ( `@Remove`).

Comment: @Joeblade Thanks for your comment. Yes, the cart actually gets populated with items as I add them to the list. Would <ui:repeat> work instead of the datatable?

Comment: @Joeblade Thank you! Thank you so much! The penny dropped wen you pointed out the error in using the instance variable (as opposed to the method variable). I am forever grateful!. I am new to Java EE and this is my MSc project. I have learnt everything up to now with very little help from anybody except you good people on Stack overflow. It has taken many sleepless nights reading many online tutorials and textbooks to understand how the facade design pattern works along side SFSB and Managed beans. Its working perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable looks like a valid way to display your list data, pretty much a copy of the [tutorial](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html)

However the way you add your data is wrong. (which is why I suggested using a debugger in comments.)

at the time of printing you should notice only 1 element in your list (I expect) or many times the same item.

Your instance variable:

```
private com.shop.entity.Orderitem basketItem=new Orderitem();
```

is reused over and over. this should be a method variable not an instance variable. You add the same instance to the list over and over, while updating it's properties. This will update the properties of *a single instance* and not create new ones. This means that if you do:

```
List list = new SomeList();
SomeObject object = new SomeObject();
list.add(object);
list.add(object);

object.setName("name");
```

the list will contain 2 references to the same object, both with name "name"

So again: this is what you are doing when you use the instance variable 
basketItem rather than make it a variable that only lives in the method addCartItem

when adding items to your cart you should use something like:

```
public boolean addCartItem(ProductEntity product, int quantityPurchased){
    for (Orderitem current : cartItems) {
        if (current.getItemCode().equals(product.getItemCode())) {
            // adding duplicate entry.
            return false; // or handle adding differently
        }
    }

    // now that we're sure that the item doesn't already exist in the basket

    Orderitem basketItem=new Orderitem();
    basketItem.setItemcode(product.getItemcode());
    basketItem.setItemdescription(product.getItemdescription());
    basketItem.setUnitprice(product.getUnitprice());
    basketItem.setQuantitypurchased(quantityPurchased);
    basketItem.setSubtotal(quantityPurchased*basketItem.getUnitprice());
    cartItems.add(basketItem);
    return true;
}
```

Next time, run your debugger and check (after adding several items to your list) what the actual contents of the list items are. That way you can probably spot that something is going wrong.